# Validate on entry or before saving?

Tags: php, oop, validation

My brain is starting to hurt so I decided I'd ask here.

I have a data object, Employee. Getters, setters, formatters, etc. I have a manager, EmployeeManager, which handles database access and other things. Right now I have a large validation block in EmployeeManager, but I've been wondering if I could move some of that to the setters.

For example, right now I have;

```
public function getSSN($bFormatted = true) { 
    return ($bFormatted) ? $this->format_ssn($this->SSN) : $this->SSN; 
}
public function setSSN($s, $bValidate = false)
{
    // If we're validating user entry, save a copy.
    // Either way, store a trimmed version.
    if ($bValidate): $this->SSNToValidate = $s; endif;
    $this->SSN = str_replace('-', '', $s);
}
public function getSSNToValidate() { return $this->SSNToValidate; }
```

What this does is:
* When you set an SSN, if it's being done by the system (like from the database) then it does `setSSN('123456789', false)`, because SSNs are stored in the database sans dashes.
* When you set an SSN from user input, it does simply `setSSN('123-45-6789')` then not only trims the dashes, but also stores a raw version to validate (because I want to validate based on format)
* When you get an SSN, if formatting is requested (and it always is except when you're writing to the database), it formats it based on another function in the Employee class.

So my question is: Could I perhaps add the validation to the setter here, instead of relying on the monolithic validate function in the Manager class? Because I'm starting to have to deal with errors coming from all over the application, I've decided for the moment to move to a central Error Handler static class, rather than each manager maintain its own list of errors.

And because of this, I could easily add error handling to this:

```
public function setSSN($s, $bFromUser = false)
{
    if ($bFromUser && !$this->validateSSN($s))
    {
        ErrorHandler::add(array('ssn' => 'Invalid SSN entered')); 
    }
    else
    {
        $this->SSN = str_replace('-', '', $s);
    }
}
```

So I guess my question is: Does this make sense at all or am I hosing myself by moving validation from the manager (to be performed on demand or just before writing to the database) to the object (to be performed on entry)?

This is overall generic, I'm just using SSN as a good example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always validate when you're creating an object or setting values in the object.  This way you are always guaranteed to have an object that is in a valid state.  If the validation is not in the object itself you can not guarantee that the object will ever be validated.

**Example validation outside of the object:**

*In this case there is a bug and we forgot to validate SSN.*

```
class EmployeeManager
{
    function saveEmployee($employee)
    {
        //Oops, we forgot to validate SSN
        $db->save($employee);  //This is just SQL to persist the employee.
    }
}

//Somewhere else in code...
$employee = new Employee();
$employee->setSSN("FredFlintstone");  //No validation is done here.
$employeeManager = new EmployeeManager();
$employeeManager->saveEmployee($employee);  //This call will persist FredFlintstone because validation was missed.
```

**Example validation inside of the object:**

*In this case the employee object validates all of it's input.  This way we know that if we have a instance of an employee all the data within it is valid.*

```
class Employee
{
    function setSSN($input)
    {
        if(strlen($input) != 9)
        {
            throw new Exception('Invalid SSN.');
        }
        //Other validations...
        $this->ssn = $input;
    }
}

//Somewhere else in code...
$employee = new Employee();
$employee->setSSN("FredFlintstone");  //This call will now throw an exception and prevent us from having a bad object.
$employeeManager = new EmployeeManager();
$employeeManager->saveEmployee($employee);
```

In addition you should never allow an object to be created that is not fully initialized.  If say a SSN is required for an employee then don't supply an empty constructor.  Your constructors should have parameters for all required fields (unlike my example which I omitted them for clarity).

Comment: Yeah, I've been seeing other people who say that maintaining the integrity of your object is paramount, meaning don't store bum data in it. If you try to add bum data, reject it. Though I've also seen that bum user input (which this is) is not exceptional, it's expected, and therefore you should handle it without an exception. But that's more semantics and programming practice, I think, than this question.

Comment: I agree that handling user data can be a pain.  I usually end up with validation called twice in that scenario: once in the UI so I can inform them of the problem and then once again in the object.  I feel it's much safer to guarantee the object will be correct and validation may be called twice than to have the possibility that I end up storing bad data.

Comment: Marking this one as the answer because I've gone with the idea of "never allow your object to be in a valid state." If I know that the SSN, for example, will never be set to an invalid figure (because it's validated on setting), then I know I don't necessarily need to validate it later. I have to learn to trust the code.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule of thumb with service-based applications is that validation should *ALWAYS* occur at the server end, shortly before persistence. Optionally you can perform validation on the client for a better user experience. But it's not safe to only perform validation at the client (ie, in your setter). Never rely on client data being right.

When doing client-based validation, it's preferable for each class (whether it's the model, view model, presenter, etc, depending on your architectural pattern) to validate itself rather than rely on some outside validator.

Comment: So maybe validate in the 'client' (the data object), and also in the manager before inserting into the database. I think my concern with that was, I'd either end up having two ValidateSSN() commands (one in the data object and one in the manager), or I'd be outsourcing it to a central Validation class... and here you are saying, don't rely on an outside validator? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Validation is always a bit tricky in this regard - there are tradeoffs between all kinds of OO principles like DRY, SRP, keep related data and behaviour together, etc. So it's not simple to answer this question. It's not uncommon to see validation logic somewhat duplicated between client and server (usually client has simpler rules for quick & dirty validation).